# How to find the extension of an image from path in PHP?

Tags: php, image

Is there any standard function in PHP to find only extension of an image from the corresponding file path?

For example ff my image path is like '/testdir/dir2/image.gif' then the function should return 'gif'.

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
$ext = pathinfo(
    parse_url('/testdir/dir2/image.gif?foo=bar', PHP_URL_PATH), 
    PATHINFO_EXTENSION
); //$ext will be gif
```

Comment: I have a `hello.jpg` but i renamed it to `hello.gif` and upload it so you get the extension but not the correct type. Pekka's aproach is IMO the better one

Comment: The original question asks for find the extension only. No security-check or other needs.

Comment: @DrColossos But thats what the OP requires - the extension. There is more chance of the OP requiring the same code for future use than renaming his images with wrong extensions.

Comment: I didn't say his answer is not correct, I just tried to explain a possibility of the downvotes.

Comment: @DrColossos: thanks for your comment, anyway currently I just need to get the file extension not the file type.

Comment: Is it possible to get the extension of an image stored remotely using the method above ?

Comment: This does not exclude query parameters.

Answer (score 15):

It's usually more desirable to detect the actual image *type* (not by extension but by its contents). For that, use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize).

Comment: This should be the correct ans. Extension in name can be anything.

Answer (score 6):

I had problem with first answer and url with anchor ex. google.com/image.jpg#anchor

better solution

```
$filename_from_url = parse_url($url);
$ext = pathinfo($filename_from_url['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the most correct way is using echo exif_imagetype function:

```
   exif_imagetype("/testdir/dir2/image.gif");

   function get_image_type($image_path){

        $extension  = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF => "gif",
        IMAGETYPE_JPEG => "jpeg",
        IMAGETYPE_PNG => "png",
        IMAGETYPE_SWF => "swf",
        IMAGETYPE_PSD => "psd",
        IMAGETYPE_BMP => "bmp",
        IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II => "tiff",
        IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM => "tiff",
        IMAGETYPE_JPC => "jpc",
        IMAGETYPE_JP2 => "jp2",
        IMAGETYPE_JPX => "jpx",
        IMAGETYPE_JB2 => "jb2",
        IMAGETYPE_SWC => "swc",
        IMAGETYPE_IFF => "iff",
        IMAGETYPE_WBMP => "wbmp",
        IMAGETYPE_XBM => "xbm",
        IMAGETYPE_ICO => "ico");

        return $extension[exif_imagetype($image_path)];
}
```

Comment: this way works even if the url is used to encode the image on the server - Well done.

Answer (score 1):

As Col. Shrapnel mentioned; there's quite a few ways

```
$path = '/some/where/img.gif';
$path = explode('.',$path);
$path = end($path);
```

Comment: thanks, this code is looking cool, but as I said above I just want to use a direct standard function like 'pathinfo'.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy way using `strrpos()` and `substr()` methods

```
$path = "/testdir/dir2/image.gif";
$ext = substr($path, strrpos($path, '.')+1);
echo $ext; // output will be gif
```

more answers for [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746518/get-image-extension) related to this Question

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to run any uploaded/linked image(s) through a GD/ImageMagick check and re-save it to prevent any malicious codes hidden within the images. This would also allow you to save all of the images with the same extension to make things easier for you.

http://www.php.net/imagepng
http://www.php.net/imagegif
http://www.php.net/imagejpeg

Comment: This is a good suggestion, even though it's not related to the question. Doesn't deserve a downvote. However, cross-converting JPG to GIF and vice versa will never lead to good results.

Comment: Thank you. I know it is not entirely related to the question, although I figured if he is to accept uploaded images it is better to spit this bit of information out before something bad happens. You could also check for the extension at first, look if the given result exists in an array of allowed extensions, and then save it as the exact same extension once run through the GD/ImageMagick check. Also keep a default (say PNG) if a result was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you perfect way

```
$file_path = '/some/where/img.gif';  
$info = new SplFileInfo($file_path);  
$file_extension = $info->getExtension(); 
var_dump($file_extension);
```

for more detail here [The SplFileInfo class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)

I hope this will help you.

Cheers!

Mudassar Ali

Answer (score -2):

Basic string functions, `strrpos()` and `substr()` can do that for you. As well as many other fancy ways.

Comment: This is a direct answer to a question where what the OP probably wants is a thorough file type check and not just one for the extension. By your logic, this would deserve a -1. Just sayin' ;)

Comment: @Pekka "to find only extension of an image". Sounds rather unambiguous to me

Comment: @Robus yes. I'm just teasing @Col because he has downvoted me for direct answers to such clear requests when the clear request was, in fact, not what the OP really needed to achieve the best solution. His feedback was always justified (I value @Col's knowledge and input very much, the PHP tag needs it) but he's always being very direct about it which is why I'm being a dick in return when he makes the same mistake :) I would like to point out that the downvote this answer has received is not from me, though.

Comment: @Pekka I hope he comes back and spanks you :P Actually I'm not sure why this was downvoted, the most upvoted answer doesn't check the actual type either just returns the extension. They're both manipulating the string rather than checking the file so not sure why someone is hating on the col.

Comment: Take it easy with Col. Shrapnel ;)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I can use these functions also but I want to use a direct standard function like 'pathinfo' instead of writing my own logic using string functions.

Comment: @Siva these functions no less standard. And you can do everything using it. Programming is NOT like LEGO - putting ready made blocks together but sometimes you have to invent something of your own. And if even such an easy thing makes you trouble, then programming probably is not your vocation. Things like pathinfo is not "standard" but rather called "syntax sugar". And too much sugar will cause diabetes.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I am not saying that those string functions are not standard. I know the power of those functions and how to use them also, but I started this thread to know about any 'DIRECT(single)' standard function to get the image extension.