# Why this php file upload validation script not working?

Tags: php

Dear friends, this is a script which simply upload file and insert filename into database, why is this not working ? It's just upload the file and send filename to db even after validation . Please help

```
<?php

//file validation starts
//split filename into array and substract full stop from the last part
$tmp = explode('.', $_FILES['photo']['name']);
$fileext= $tmp[count($tmp)-1];

//read the extension of the file that was uploaded
$allowedexts = array("png");
if(in_array($fileext, $allowedexts)){
    return true;
}else{
    $form_error= "Upload file was not supported<br />";
    header('Location: apply.php?form_error=' .urlencode($form_error));
}


//file validation ends

//upload dir for pics
$uploaddir = './uploads/';


//upload file in folder
$uploadfile = $uploaddir. basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);


//insert filename in mysql db
$upload_filename = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);



//upload the file now
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

// $photo value is goin to db
$photo = $upload_filename;
```

Comment: What part is not working?  What sort of error or behaviour are you getting instead?

Comment: It seems your file extension detection fails. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179294/how-to-find-the-extension-of-an-image-from-path-in-php/3179305#3179305

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function send_error($error = 'Unknown error accured')
{
    header('Location: apply.php?form_error=' .urlencode($error));
    exit; //!!!!!!
}
//file validation starts
//split filename into array and substract full stop from the last part

$fileext = end(explode('.', $_FILES['photo']['name'])); //Ricky Dang | end()

//read the extension of the file that was uploaded
$allowedexts = array("png");
if(!in_array($fileext, $allowedexts))
{
}

//upload dir for pics
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
if(!is_dir($uploaddir))
{
    send_error("Upload Directory Error");
}    

//upload file in folder
$uploadfile = $uploaddir. basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

if(!file_exists($uploadfile ))
{
    send_error("File already exists!");
}

//insert filename in mysql db
$upload_filename = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

//upload the file now
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
    send_error('Upload Failed, cannot move file!');
}

// $photo value is goin to db
$photo = $upload_filename;
```

This is a cleared up version to yours, give that a go and see if you get any errors

Answer (score 0):

You can find the extension of file by using this code also.

```
$tmp = end(explode('.', $_FILES['photo']['name']));
```

now `$tmp` got the extension of file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use PHP's built-in functions to extract the extension from the filename?

```
$fileext = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

And if the file extension is valid, you're returning from the function without doing anything further, if it's invalid you're setting the header, but the code logic will continue to your file processing

Comment: +1 valid answer - very helpful and I hate when people downvote and don't comment.

Comment: Make sure that you don't rely on the given file extension. Changing a files extenstion is no problem at all. I see that your variable is named "photo" - so take a look at getimgagesize(): http://php.net/getimagesize

Answer (score 0):

You blindly assume the file upload succeeded, but there's many reasons for it to fail, which is why PHP provides `['error']` in the $_FILES array:

```
if ($_FILES['photo']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    // uploaded properly, handle it here...
} else {
    die("File upload error, code #" . $_FILES['photo']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are [defined here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).