# Get image extension

Tags: php, image

I want get uploaded image extension.

As I know, best way is `getimagesize()` function.

but this function's mime,  returns `image/jpeg` when image has `.jpg` or also `.JPEG` extension.

How can get exactly extension?

Comment: Why do you care about the extension? I could upload a jpeg with a `.png` extension, but you'd still be able to see that its a jpeg with other methods.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can use [`image_type_to_extension`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-extension.php) function with image type returned by `getimagesize`:

```
$info = getimagesize($path);
$extension = image_type_to_extension($info[2]);
```

Comment: @phpalix's answer does not support a file without an explicit extension (example: an image in the tmp directory), but this script solves this type of problem.

Answer (score 33):

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use strrpos and substr functions to get extension of any file

```
$filePath="images/ajax-loader.gif";

$type=substr($filePath,strrpos($filePath,'.')+1);

echo "file type=".$type;
```

> output: gif

if you want extension like .gif

```
$type=substr($filePath,strrpos($filePath,'.')+0);
```

> output: .gif

Comment: What is the meaning of `strrpost($filePath, '.')+0`

Answer (score 4):

```
$image = explode(".","test.file.hhh.kkk.jpg");
echo end($image);
```

Comment: how about files containing . in the name?

Comment: @dfsq, You give me test.file.jpg but Now check that men with 4 dot.

Comment: @dfsq, now must reply dude.

Comment: I did not downvote. However downvotes were reasonable, you are not agree?

Comment: @dfsq , thanks because of your comment i can understand where i made mistake.

Comment: No problem, and you came up with better solution.

Answer (score 3):

One more way to do it:

```
$ext = strrchr($filename, "."); // .jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

or to make it clean

```
$filename= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file_ext = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also explode the file name with dots and take the end of the array as follows:

```
$ext = end(explode('.', 'image.name.gif'));
```

According to: [Two different ways to find file extension in PHP](http://sikitech.blogspot.com/2013/02/two-different-ways-to-find-file.html)

And a new way for you lol:

```
$ext = explode('.', 'file.name.lol.lolz.jpg');
echo $ext[count($ext) - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to check if image type is JPEG, PNG or etc. You can use [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) function. This function reads the first bytes of an image and checks its signature. Here is a simple example from php.net:

```
<?php
if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
   echo 'The picture is not a gif';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$size = getimagesize($filename);
$ext = explode('/', $size['mime'])[1];
```