# Whose temporary directory an upload script uses?

Tags: php, file-upload, web-hosting

I am building a upload feature on my project.I have done other validation on exist,size and type but there were some little more validation needed.I found out mime validation where no matter what file extension a user upload it checks the real file type.Below code did that work for me.Now whenever a user try to upload .php file as a .png/jpg/jpeg or any other fake extension name my code catches as malicious file type.But I have a question that when a user upload a file at first it goes on temporary directory.Is that temporary directory is used from client pc or from our server?If its from our server then will that malicious fake extension file can be dangerous for us or not?

```
$imageInfo = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    if ($imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/png") || $imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/jpeg")
            || $imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/jpg")) {
```

Comment: My upload application is only made for file type image.(jpg,jpeg and png are the only image extension which my upload application supports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> Files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary directory, unless another location has been given with the [upload_tmp_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) directive in `php.ini`. The server's default directory can be changed by setting the environment variable TMPDIR in the environment in which PHP runs.

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

---

Unless you do something intentionally stupid like run files found within that temporary directory, or cause them to be run, you're fine. It's not dangerous for a file to simply exist for a short period of time only to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

the temp directory is from your server, and it is possible to execute files in the temp directory, so  you can run the sys_get_temp_dir() so you can know the location of the temp directory and change the permission to Read and Write only.

Answer (score 0):

first get extension then use extension in if condition like this :

```
$extension = image_type_to_extension($imageInfo[2]);
```

Comment: The getimagesize() function will determine the size of any given image file and return the dimensions along with the file type and a height/width text string to be used inside a normal HTML IMG tag and the correspondant HTTP content type.

Comment: print $extension then check get extension or not

Comment: and see the url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746518/get-image-extension

Comment: `$filename =   $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 $fileextension = strtolower(substr($filename, strpos($filename, '.')+1));` i can get an extension like this way too.I'm happy that getimagesize function let's me mime info.