# How to get image extension

Tags: php

In my pregame, user need to upload an image, and system will rename to a serial number.

After I rename it the extension of the file is missing (.jpg/.png)

How can I get get the file extension

upload.php

```
$nric=$_SESSION['nric'];
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    $num=(rand(10,100));
    $serialNumber = "TM".$userID.$num.$nric[7].$nric[8];
    $_FILES['file']['name']=$serialNumber;
    $file=strtoupper($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$folder="uploads/";
```

Comment: Is $_POST['upload'] the original file name?

Comment: Possiible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746518/get-image-extension

Comment: Before overwriting `$_FILES['file']['name']` with `$serialNumber`, extract the extension from it and append it to your new filename.

Comment: @MuhammedAshik is none of the answers correct? You should mark the one you found best as correct and if any of the other was helpful, you should upvote them. Not doing so will probably mean people are less likely to help you in the future

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
pathinfo($folder.$file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
```

With this code you can get the extension of the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

If $_POST['upload'] is the original file name as I asked in the comments, then:

```
$ext = explode(".", $_POST['upload'])[1];
echo $ext; //gives jpg, gif or whatever the extension is
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$nric=$_SESSION['nric'];
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
  $file = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $newfilename = "TM".$userID.$num.$nric[7].$nric[8] . '.' . end($file);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename);
}
```

OR

```
//Create a function that takes care of the randomization
function randStrGen($len){
$result = "";
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$11"; //Characters allowed to produce a random string
$charArray = str_split($chars);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    $randItem = array_rand($charArray);
    $result .= "".$charArray[$randItem];
}
return $result;
}

$rand = randStrGen(24); //The amount of random characters needed
$nric=$_SESSION['nric']; //Session variable
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
 $file = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 $newfilename = $rand . '.' . end($file);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename); // Change this to your server's image directory
}
```

OR BETTER STILL

```
if (isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extension
$file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
$filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$allowed_file_types = array('.jpg','.png','.gif','.jpeg');  

if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 200000))
{   
    // Rename file
    $newfilename = "TM" . md5($file_basename) . $userID. $num . $file_ext;
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $newfilename))
    {
        // file already exists error
        echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
    }
    else
    {       
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename);
        echo "File uploaded successfully.";     
    }
}
elseif (empty($file_basename))
{   
    // file selection error
    echo "Please select a file to upload.";
} 
elseif ($filesize > 200000)
{   
    // file size error
    echo "The file you are trying to upload is too large.";
}
else
{
    // file type error
    echo "Only these file types are allowed for upload: " . implode(', ',$allowed_file_types);
    unlink($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
}
}
```

What you basically need is
    //Change $file
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($file, '.')); // get file extension