# php get file extension from image

Tags: php

so i want to get the file extension from the img so if i upload a image i can use mutiple file exts but when i use this code to get the file ext it does not work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['user_id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if ($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
                $filename = "../assets/IMGS/profile/Avatar".$id.".*";
                $fileinfo = glob($filename);
                $fileext = explode(".", $fileinfo[0]);
                $fileactualext = $fileext[1];

                echo "<img src='../assets/IMGS/profile/Avatar".$id.".".$fileactualext."?".mt_rand()."'>";
            } else {
                echo '<img src="../assets/IMGS/profile/def-image.png">';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are asking, please review the guidelines on asking questions.

This way you are more likely to get a response quickly if we can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746518/get-image-extension

Duplicate

Comment: can you please update some images names????

Comment: why the nested sql queries both querying the users table? You might find `pathinfo( $file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ` useful

Comment: If someone update his picture with different file extension than previous one, this code will fail $filename = "../assets/IMGS/profile/Avatar".$id.".*";

Comment: You can actually write your SQL queries on one single query using `SQL JOIN` - Also its not 100 % clear whats not working here. Do you get any output? Do you get errors?

Comment: you don't even need to do a join - it's one table being queried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your filepath with image and store ina variable `$filename` then try this

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
$extension =  $path_parts['extension'];
?>
```