# Check what a variable ends with?

Tags: php, function, variables

I'm stuck in my code.

My site's users are supposed to give me the link of a image that I will store in a variable.
How can I check what the link ends with, the extension if you will?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the extension of an image from path in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179294/how-to-find-the-extension-of-an-image-from-path-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of these:

```
$ext = substr(strrchr(FILENAME, '.'), 1);

$ext = substr(FILENAME, strrpos(FILENAME, '.') + 1);

$ext = preg_replace('/^.*\.([^.]+)$/D', '$1', FILENAME);
```

Their performance differences are negligible *(even when ran like a 500 000 times; tested with PHP 7 using [phpcb](https://github.com/smuuf/phpcb))*

The `pathinfo()` is like... really slow, compared to these, for just getting the *(last)* extension.

Comment: Thank you for giving performance info, I didn't know pathinfo() lagged behind so bad compared to alternatives methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring method "substr" to get the last couple characters after the last occuring period which you can find with "strrpos" I believe.

`strrpos` ([See doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)) returns false if the last occurrence wasn't found and the index of the match if it is.

```
$mystring = 'stackoverflow.png';
$pos = strrpos($mystring,'.');

if($pos === false) { // Note the triple '='
    // not found..
}else{
    echo substr($mystring, $pos); // print '.png'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Jefferson answer is correct; based on the problem an easier solution would be to use **PATHINFO_EXTENSION**.

```
pathinfo('/path/to/file/image.jpg', PHPINFO_EXTENSION); // returns 'jpg'
```